# How can I speed up a mongoDB (mongoose) batch insert with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a bunch of documents in a collection I need to copy and insert into the collection, changing only the parent_id on all of them. This is taking a very very long time and maxing out my CPU. This is the current implementation I have. I only need to change the parent_id on all the documents.

```
// find all the documents that need to be copied
models.States.find({parent_id: id, id: { $in: progress} }).exec(function (err, states) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw err;
    } 

    var insert_arr = [];

    // copy every document into an array
    for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        // copy with the new id
        insert_arr.push({
            parent_id: new_parent_id,
            id: states[i].id,
            // data is a pretty big object
            data: states[i].data,
        })
    }

    // batch insert
    models.States.create(insert_arr, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        } 
    });
});
```

Here is the schema I am using

```
var states_schema = new Schema({
    id : { type: Number, required: true },
    parent_id : { type: Number, required: true },
    data : { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true }
});
```

There must be a better way to do this that I just cannot seem to come up with. Any suggestions are more than welcome! Thanks.

Comment: You need to save them in the same collection?

Comment: @SalvadorDali They don't necessarily need to be in the same collection. How would saving them to a different one be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a case there is no point to do this on application layer. Just do this in database.

```
db.States.find({parent_id: id, id: { $in: progress} }).forEach(function(doc){
  delete doc._id;
  doc.parentId = 'newParentID';
  db.States.insert(doc);
})
```

If you really need to do this in mongoose, I see the following problem:
 your return all the documents that matches your criteria, then you iterate though them and copy them into another array (modifying them), then you iterate through modified elements and copy them back. So this is at least 3 times longer then what I am doing.

**P.S.** If you need to save to different collection, you should change `db.States.insert(doc)` to `db.anotherColl.insert(doc)`

**P.S.2** If you can not do this from the shell, I hope you can find a way to insert my query into mongoose.

Comment: I wish I could do this from the shell.